# url working in local not on server showing parse error

Tags: php, xml

I am hitting on a url and get data this is working in local but giving error on online server.
errors messages are

```
simplexml_load_file(): http://test.com/search/abc.exe?pageid=4&xyzid=1:1: parser error : Document is empty in /project/haroon/temp-4-test/search.php on line 54
```

line 54 in my file is

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("url same as abovein error");
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must check your file path.

Marco

Comment: File path is correct.   it shows warnings 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Answer (score 0):

check with server php.ini settings. Looks it is blocking PHP file load requests for some user agents. Try setting ini value to ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'); before you make the request.

Comment: I set ini value as ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0');
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));  is also return 1 but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code on your server:

```
<?php var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')); ?>
```

If it returns 0 then your server is not permitted to open URLs as files. Your hosting provider would have disabled this in the PHP settings.

Comment: Thanks .. it return 1.. but issue is not resolved yet

Comment: Could you upload the whole project to Git so I can have a look at it?